# Temporarily hide scope on store

Tags: scope, scope-switcher

at the moment we have setup two scopes on our store which is not live yet. English and Danish. We want to go live with only Danish scope, until there is need for English as well and also we need time to translate everything in products, categories etc.

Is this doable and can we change this in webadmin? Can we just hide store swicher ?

Answer (score 0):

Goto Stores -> Configuration
In the panel on the left under General
-> select General
Goto bottom. Select  Single Store Mode to YES
and Flush the Cache